# WebDriver Selenium SendKeys Issue Firefox 26

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I am using Selenium webdriver 2.41.0 with FF 26.

I had an issue while using SendKeys to send value to a textfield.

I use SendKeys to send character to text field. It types successfully, but when I submit the value of the text field seeems to be empty as it cannot be processed.

But if I retype manually, it successfully submitted. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on an element other than the one you typed in.  It's possibly a javascript driven `value` that isn't being set until blur or loss of focus of the element you typed in.

Comment: You may need to find an older version of WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the 'type' of input tag. Method sendKeys is not working for type='number' for few FF updates.

Comment: It works on Google Chrome though! is this because of compatibility or smth perhaps?